# Casting: Same Types in debug mode but unable to cast

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, generics, types

I have an extremely odd issue.  I am trying to cast an object, and even though during debug mode it shows the two objects as identical it fails to cast.  Here is the code

```
if (messageResponse is T)
            {
                response = (T)messageResponse;
            }
```

When in debug mode I hover is and it evaluates to true but it skips the if block and goes to the else, now shown here.  Also, when I force execution into the if block I get this error message

> [A]AutoAnything.BusinessServer.Messages.GetConfigurationSettingMessageResponse`1[AutoAnything.BusinessServer.DataObjects.Settings.ApplicationManager.ApplicationSettings] cannot be cast to 
>   [B]AutoAnything.BusinessServer.Messages.GetConfigurationSettingMessageResponse`1[AutoAnything.BusinessServer.DataObjects.Settings.ApplicationManager.ApplicationSettings]
>   . Type A originates from 
>   'AutoAnything.BusinessServer.Messages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2dc64af3\f4e18fc8\assembly\dl3\88929564\4b299f15_0bfecb01\AutoAnything.BusinessServer.Messages.DLL'. Type B originates from 
>   'AutoAnything.BusinessServer.Messages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2dc64af3\f4e18fc8\assembly\dl3\88929564\4b299f15_0bfecb01\AutoAnything.BusinessServer.Messages.DLL'.

As you can see objects [A] and [B] are said to be identical.  Has anyone ever seen this before?  Also, I am using reflection to call the containing method of the code above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that when you evaluate an expression in the debugger it is not actually running the code.  Instead it's actually doing something much closer to interpreting the expression in question.

In general the interpretation produces the same results as actual code evaluation but there are cases where it fails.  One of the more difficult areas to get right is types.  It's very likely that the debugger is simply incorrectly evaluating that expression on the hover.

Comment: Is there anyway to get output what these types may be?  Trace.WriteLine, or any other suggestions?

Comment: Also what about the error message?  Is that just an interpretation or is that the actual running code?

Comment: I tried Trace.Writeline and it is still outputting the same thing unfortunately

Comment: @Lizzard, does the type in question have an implicit conversion operator?

Comment: @JaredPar, no it does not have an implicit conversion operator

Comment: @Lizzard what did you actually put in the `Trace.WriteLine`?

Comment: @JaredPar - Trace.WriteLine("T - " + messageResponse.GetType());
Trace.WriteLine("T - " + typeof(T));

Comment: @Lizzard try `TraceLine.Write(messageResponse is T)`.  That's the actual expression in question that's problematic

Comment: @JaredPar alright so that did evaluate out to false in the Trace.WriteLine.  But the GetType and typeof calls return the same thing, any idea of what I should look for or how to find what is different between the two?  Also, thanks for all your help so far

Comment: @Lizzard, I'm having a hard time coming up with a good reason. The only suspcion I have left is that it's the same `GetConfigurationSettingMessageResponse` type but it's instatiated with different `ApplicationSettings` types.  That would make them incompatible and explain the error message.

Comment: @JaredPar     var request = new GetConfigurationSettingMessage
            {
                ConfigurationType = typeof(T),
                ApplicationInstanceId = applicationInstanceId
            };               GetConfigurationSettingMessageResponse<T> ch;          Just an FYI when I try to run the code with Generics like I have shown here it gives me problems but when I replace it with a specific class name it executes fine